# Get file from ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget, mailx

I have an Ubuntu server running with DB backups. How to get the backups? I am using a *.pem file to login. I have been trying mail with mailx. I execute the command but without success. I get no error messages

```
echo "something" | mailx -s "subject" mymail@gmail.com
```

I am aware of that this is without attachments. How to get this working? With wget do I need a url?

Comment: wget will work if you have an external ip.

Comment: how can i find out if it is external?

Comment: Try and access it externally.

Comment: pasting the IP in the browser does not work so I guess it is not external.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using `scp` which runs over SSH and thus far more secure than `wget`. You need to have an SSH server running to do this.

Comment: i connect to the server with SSH. But how do I fetch my file?

Comment: $scp -i myPem.pem  /home/ubuntu/logo.png  ubuntu@ec2-77-237-115-112.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/   ......../home/ubuntu/logo.png: No such file or directory

Comment: The file is there I sure about but I see others have had the same problem so I am searching

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage to get a file to your working directory is

```
$ scp -i myPem.pem  ubuntu@ec2-77-237-115-112.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/logo.png .
```